# javascript trouble with the setattributefunction

Tags: javascript, html, function, setattribute

I use a form that display some div depending on which option you click of the radio button.

The thing is that the div is set to be none displayed, except if I select an option.

So I added the following function in order to make sure that if the div is displayed it will have th form havin the required property.

SO I give this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addattribute()
{
    if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementsByName('montant_creance').setAttribute('required');
        document.getElementsByName('condition2').setAttribute('required');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementsByName('montant_creance').setAttribute('required','false');
        document.getElementsByName('condition2').setAttribute('required','false');
    }
}
</script>
```

But It say to me in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'setAttribute'`

I really do not know how to find an issue.

Receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind Regards.

SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName` return a collection of elements, so you have to write e.g.

```
document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required');
```

every time you use this method (or similar methods, like `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`...) using the right index

Comment: thanks a lot, I'put what you told me; and now it say to me An invalid form control with name='condition2' is not focusable.

Comment: if you feel this issue is not related with your original question you should open a new discussion and post some code to see in a demo page /fiddle/jsbin otherwise just post a link with some code

Comment: in fact it works except that When I click back to the first option and the div is set to not be displayed it show this message.

Answer (score 0):

the setAttribute takes 2 parameters name and value:

```
setAttribute('name','value');
```

Comment: Dear Sir that is what I wrote setAttribute('required','false');

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function addattribute()
{
 if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "block")
 {
  document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required');
  document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required');
 }
 if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "none")
 {
  document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required','false');
  document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required','false');
 }
}
</script> I have this

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function addattribute() { if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "block") { document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required','true'); document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required','true'); } if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "none") { document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required','fals‌​e'); document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required','false'); } } </script>